# Symfony event listener service shared

Tags: php, symfony, event-listener

I have event listener as service, declared as:

```
#[Autoconfigure(shared: true)]
#[AutoconfigureTag(name: 'doctrine.event_listener', attributes: [
    'event' => Events::preUpdate,
    'entity' => User::class,
    'method' => 'preUpdate',
])]
#[AutoconfigureTag(name: 'doctrine.event_listener', attributes: [
    'event' => Events::postFlush,
    'method' => 'postFlush',
])]
class Sender
```

Unfortunately, symfony create for preUpdate and postFlush another object, so I cannot used shared this.

What's wrong with it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You created two aliace with same name, symfony will choose 1st one.
I believe it should be like:

```
#[AutoconfigureTag(name: 'doctrine.event_listener.preUpdate', attributes: [
    'entity' => User::class,
    'method' => 'preUpdate',
])]
#[AutoconfigureTag(name: 'doctrine.event_listener.postFlush', attributes: [
    'method' => 'postFlush',
])]
```